# On a maximum of a determinant with dependent variables

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, determinant

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in [-1,1]^n$ and define the function
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n):= \prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=i}^n\left(1-\prod_{k=i}^j x_k\right).$$
This is a positive function, and **actually coincides with the determinant of a $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix** $M:=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{n+1}$ where:
$$a_{i,i}=1, \hspace{0.5cm}1\leq i\leq n+1,$$
$$a_{i+1,i}=1, \hspace{0.5cm} i=1\leq i\leq n,$$
$$a_{i,j}=x_i^{j-1} \cdot x_{i+1}^{j-i-1}\cdots x_{j-1}, \hspace{0.5cm}j>i,$$
$$a_{i,j}= x_{j+1}\cdot x_{j+2}^2\cdots x_{i-1}^{i-j-1}, \hspace{0.5cm}j<i-1.$$

Thanks to the definition of $M$, we immediately get $f\leq (n+1)^{(n+1)/2}$ by Hadamard's Lemma. But actually it is possible to get sharper estimates.

In 1977 M. Pohst https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X77900075 proved 
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\leq 2^{[(n+1)/2]}\hspace{0.5cm}\forall n\leq 11,$$
where the brackets denote the floor integer part. His result was improved in 1996 by M. J. Bertin http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa74/aa7444.pdf who proved 
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\leq 2^{[(n+1)/2]}\hspace{0.5cm}\forall n.$$
However, while I have no problems with Pohst's proof, **I have some troubles with Bertin's one**.

The key idea of her proof is the following: the maximum of the function $f$, seen as determinant of $M$, is estimated by the maximum of determinants of matrices similar to $M$ where the $x_i's$ are in $\{-1,0,1\}.$ In other words, the maximum is attained pushing the $x_i's$ to the boundary of their defining intervals.

My problem is that I am not convinced by this argument: I would agree that the maximum of the determinant is attained by pushing the elements of $M$ to the boundary **if all these elements were independent of each other** (the determinant would be an harmonic function of its variables). But this is not the case for $M$: once you have settled $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ you immediately have all the remaining elements of the matrix.
Just look at the first line, formed by $1, x_1, x_1^2x_2, x_1^3x_2^2x_3$ and so on.

In the end, I do not get an exhaustive explanation of the estimate from the paper: **is there some step or detail that I am missing**? Any suggestion is well accepted.